# Finding the longest substring between a "start" string and one of 3 possible "end" strings

Tags: java, string, parsing, indexing

So my question is substring-related.

How do you find the longest possible substring between a starting string and one of three ending strings? I also need to find the index of the original string that the largest substring starts at.

So:

Start string: 
"ATG"

3 possible end strings:
"TAG"
"TAA"
"TGA"

An example original string might be:
"SDAFKJDAFKATGDFSDFAKJDNKSJFNSDTGASDFKJSDNKFJSNDJFATGDSDFKJNSDFTAGSDFSDATGFF"
So the result of that should give me:
- Longest substring length: 23 (from the substring ATGDFSDFAKJDNKSJFNSDTGA)
- Index of longest substring: 10

I cannot use Regex.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)  I mean *besides* asking us.

Comment: it seems the longest substring is `ATGDFSDFAKJDNKSJFNSDTGASDFKJSDNKFJSNDJFATGDSDFKJNSDFTAG`. how do you say `ATGDFSDFAKJDNKSJFNSDTGA` is longest? i dont understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is arguably the easiest way, and it's just one line:

```
String target = str.replaceAll(".*ATG(.*)(TAG|TAA|TGA).*", "$1");
```

To find the index:

```
int index = str.indexOf("ATG") + 3;
```

---

Note: I have interpreted your remark "I cannot use regex" to mean "I am unskilled at regex", because if it's a java question, regex is available.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this looks like a fun one.

It seems the most straightforward way to do this would be to build your own mini finite state machine. You would have to parse each character in the string and keep track of all possible character sequences that would terminate the sequence.

If you hit a 'T', you need to jump ahead and look at the next character. If it's an 'A' or a 'G' you need to jump ahead again, otherwise, add those tokens to your string. Continue the pattern until you get to the end of the original string, or match one of your terminal patterns.

So, maybe something that looks like this (simplified example):

```
String longestSequence(String original) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  char[] tokens = original.toCharArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; ++i) {
    // read each token, and compare / look ahead to see if you should keep going or terminate.
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

match your string to this regex:

```
ATG[A-Z]+(TAG|TAA|TGA)
```

if multiple match occurs then iterate and keep the one with highest length.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    // using pattern with flags
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ATG[A-Z]+(TAG|TAA|TGA)");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( yourInputStringHere );

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found the text \"" + matcher.group()
                + "\" starting at " + matcher.start()
                + " and ending at index " + matcher.end());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are already some beautiful and elegant solutions to your problem (Bohemian and inquisitive). If you still - as originally stated - can't use regex, here's an alternative. This code is not especially elegant, and as pointed, there are better ways to do it, but it should at least clearly show you the logic behind the solution to your problem.

> How do you find the longest possible substring between a starting string 
>   and one of three ending strings?

First, find the index of starting string, then find the index of each ending string, and get substrings for each ending, then their length. Remember that if string is not found, its index will be -1.

```
    String originalString = "SDAFKJDAFKATGDFSDFAKJDNKSJFNSDTGASDFKJSDNKFJSNDJFATGDSDFKJNSDFTAGSDFSDATGFF";

    String STARTING_STRING = "ATG";

    String END1 = "TAG";
    String END2 = "TAA";
    String END3 = "TGA";

    //let's find the index of STARTING_STRING
    int posOfStartingString = originalString.indexOf(STARTING_STRING);

    //if found
    if (posOfStartingString != -1) {
        int tagPos[] = new int[3];

        //let's find the index of each ending strings in the original string
        tagPos[0] = originalString.indexOf(END1, posOfStartingString+3);
        tagPos[1] = originalString.indexOf(END2, posOfStartingString+3);
        tagPos[2] = originalString.indexOf(END3, posOfStartingString+3);

        int lengths[] = new int[3];

        //we can now use the following methods:
        //public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
        //where beginIndex is our posOfStartingString
        //and endIndex is position of each ending string (if found)
        //
        //and finally, String.length() to get the length of each substring

        if (tagPos[0] != -1) {
            lengths[0] = originalString.substring(posOfStartingString, tagPos[0]).length();
        }
        if (tagPos[1] != -1) {
            lengths[1] = originalString.substring(posOfStartingString, tagPos[1]).length();
        }
        if (tagPos[2] != -1) {
            lengths[2] = originalString.substring(posOfStartingString, tagPos[2]).length();
        }

    } else {
        //no starting string in original string
    }
```

lengths[] table now contains length of strings starting with STARTING_STRING and 3 respective endings. Then just find which one is the longest and you will have your answer.

> I also need to find the index of the original string that the largest substring starts at.

This will be the index of where starting string starts, in this case 10.